# Logstash : Using codec Plain and JSON for the same input

Tags: logstash, filebeat

Actually we have this architecture : Filebeat --> Kafaka --> Logstash

The Logstash is using this input config :

**file1.conf**

```
input {
  kafka {
    codec => json
    bootstrap_servers => "....."
    topics_pattern => [ "prd*" ]
    auto_offset_reset => earliest
    decorate_events => true
  }
}
filter {
...
}
```

**file2.conf**

```
input {
  kafka {
    codec => plain
    bootstrap_servers => "....."
    topics_pattern => [ "prd*" ]
    auto_offset_reset => earliest
    decorate_events => true
  }
}
filter {
...
}
```

So for file1 we use JSON codec and for file2 we use PLAIN.

Now we are going to remove the Kafka so will have this : Filebeat --> Logstash

```
input {
  beats {
    port => 5044
    codec => plain
    ssl => true
    ssl_certificate_authorities => ["/etc/ca.crt"]
    ssl_certificate => "/etc/logstash.crt"
    ssl_key => "/etc/logstash.key"
    ssl_verify_mode => "force_peer"
  }
}
```

The problem is when previously we had 2 input : one for JSON and one for PLAIN, i can't see how to that with a single INPUT Beats ?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible, you can have only one codec in the input.

What you need to do is filter the messages where you would use the json codec and use a json filter, it is basically the same thing.

You didn't share your filebeat input, but you could add a [custom field](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/beats/filebeat/current/filebeat-input-filestream.html#filebeat-input-filestream-fields) and use it to filter in logstash.

Would be something like this:

```
if [fields][codec_to_use] == "json" {
    json {
        source => "message"
    }
}
```